# how to set attributes and remove attributes on two details element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar with a drop-down menu using a `<details>` tag

```js
sum.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
  details.setAttribute("open", "open");
});

sum.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
  details.removeAttribute("open", "open");
});
```

I want to add and remove an attribute when the mouse hovers over the details tag. It seems work on the first drop-down, but didn't work on the second drop-down. Please help!

Comment: u can check the full code on this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-http-kslzx?file=/index.js:95-283

Comment: Do you really mean HTML attribute or CSS style?

Comment: You only search for one result, and your querySelector will just return the first. You need to implement it twice by specifying an id in HTML or you will have to query select multiple results and loop over them.

Comment: @Carles html tag <details></details>

Comment: @Tom yeah i dont know how,for loop right?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but what about using the CSS attribute display, that you can set to "block" to display a TAG and "none" to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `Document` method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Below, you are selecting the first `details` and `summary` nested within it.

```js
let details = document.querySelector("details");
let sum = document.querySelector("summary");
```

You can instead use `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
let details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
let sum = document.querySelectorAll("summary");

sum.forEach((sum, index) => {
  sum.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
    details[index].setAttribute("open", "open");
    console.log(details[index]);
  });

  sum.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    details[index].removeAttribute("open", "open");
    console.log(details[index]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not working? If you check the console, you will see the attribute being added and removed.